# Cannot select from new view in MySQL (can select from everything else)

Tags: mysql, security

I am a newbie to MySQL, being more accustomed to MSSQL.  However, we have recently purchased the LabTech management software, which uses a MySQL back end.  While writing a custom report to keep track of the status of the network, I added a new view.  The new view works just fine when executed as root, but when running it as a user I get:

Error Code: 1142
SELECT command denied to user 'username'@'remote_address' for table 'new_view'

I am using MySQL Workbench to administer the database and I cannot see anywhere to view the permissions of the view.  I have tried

GRANT SELECT ON labtech.new_view TO 'username'@'localhost';
flush privileges;

but that has not helped.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean `'username'@'remote_address'` in that `GRANT` command?  'localhost' and 'remote_address' are different users to mysql.

Comment: That was it.  I didn't realize that MySQL considers the host as well as the username.  Thanks!  If you add that as an answer I'll credit you

Comment: But now I can't seem to access anything ELSE in the database as that user

Comment: what does SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'remote_address' tell you?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the same problem as you! When I recover the mysql data, it happens. Then I found its **DEFINER** user was not the one I have set. Just use:

```
SELECT DEFINER FROM information_schema.views WHERE table_schema='labtech' LIMIT 10;
```

to show the **DEFINER** , you will find it was the older user. To modify it, I think you should look at [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/modify-definer-on-many-views) on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/modify-definer-on-many-views).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you recognize that mysql recognizes the address as part of the username.